# Time travel movie: police officer/government agent observes the past through a wormhole to prevent a terrorist attack

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I was talking with some friends about a movie that I saw maybe five years ago that starred Jim Caviezel, Val Kilmer and possibly Denzel Washington.

It was about this guy that was a police officer or government agent that was brought in to help observe the past through a wormhole to try to learn who was behind a terrorist attack.

In the end he goes back him time himself to prevent the attack.

Comment: This could have *easily* been found by looking at [Denzel Washington](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000243/)'s recent movies on imdb: [Deja Vu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453467/)

Answer (score 8):

The movie you are looking for is [*Deja Vu*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453467/).

[image: Déjà Vu poster]

The movie stars:

- Denzel Washington - Agent Doug Carlin - ATF
- Paula Patton - Claire Kuchever
- Val Kilmer - Agent Paul Pryzwarra - FBI
- Jim Caviezel - Carroll Oerstadt

> A ferry filled with crewmen from the USS Nimitz and their families was blown up in New Orleans on Mardi Gras. BATF Doug Carlin is brought in to assist in the massive investigation, and gets attached to an experimental FBI surveillance unit, one that uses spacefolding technology to directly look back a little over four days into the past. While tracking down the bomber, Carlin gets an idea in his head: could they use the device to actually travel back in time and not only prevent the bombing but also the murder of a local woman whose truck was used in the bombing?

Comment: Beat me to it.  Well done.